# Dynamic Summing Range

Tags: excel, vba, sum, excel-2010

Currently I have a medical spread-sheet with a list of clients that we have serviced. We have 8 different clinical categories which are denoted by different acronyms  - HV,SV,CV,WV,CC,OV,TS and GS.

A client can receive multiple therapies i.e. HV,SV,CV - in the background we have a counter mechanism which would increment each of these records by 1.The formula used for this counter is:
`=(LEN('Parent Sheet'!F25)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE('Parent Sheet'!F25,'Parent Sheet'!$P$4,"")))/LEN('Parent Sheet'!$P$4)`

[image: Snapshot of spreadsheet]

At the bottom of the sheet we then have a sum which ads up all the treatments that occurred for that week.
[image: Summed Totals Sample]

Now the tricky part about this is that we have almost a year's worth of data in this sheet but the summing formulas are set as: `SUM(COLUMN 6: COLUMN 53)` but due to a need to increase the entries beyond this limit, we have to adjust the sum formula. We have 300 SUM Formulas adding up each of the 8 Criteria items and assigning them to the HV,SV,SC,WV etc. counters.

Would we have to adjust this manually one by one or is there a easier way of doing this?
[image: Snapshot of Counter][image]

Thank you very much!

Comment: It's very hard for us to figure out what's going on if you don't include the Row and Column headings. also please include a bit more than just 1 day/week. If there is a pattern to it, we have figure a better way, even to use VBA to place in formulas. Please include some real life data without sensitive contents. Is it just one worksheet you are dealing with (**Parent Sheet**)?

Comment: Hi Patrick, please refer to the image below I've uploaded. The data is scrubbed already. http://i.stack.imgur.com/mfsXs.png   And there is more than just the one spread-sheet. There is a secondary sheet known as the running-total sheet which incrementally increases for each instance of a particular medical condition. This is significant because a client can receive multiple therapies HV,HV,SV,CC (For example) over the course of a week. With a large number of clients all having different instances of HV etc. occuring, you'd have to do a loop to go through all entries.

Comment: Can you label your images with the corresponding Worksheet name? It's getting confusing what you try to do now. The UDF in my answer is to replace your way of counting HV, etc. It's hard to talk about cell locations when your images don't have Column & Row headings.

Comment: @azurekirby I asked this earlier : Does row refer to a client? So if a client is having multiple treatment for a day, these treatments are added by rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, I think you should change the sheet layout a little, create a User Defined Function (UDF) and alter the formulas in your Sum rows for efficient row/column adding (to make use of Excel's formula fill). The only issue is that you need to save this as a Macro-Enabled file.

What you need to change in the formulas is to utilize **`$`** to restrict changes in column and rows when the formula fill takes place.

To illustrate in an example, consider:
[image: data]
Assuming the first data starts at row 6, and no more than row 15 (you can use the idea of another data gap on the top). Alter the Sum row titles to begin with the abbreviation then create a UDF like below:

```
Option Explicit

' The oRngType refers to a cell where the abbreviation is stored
' The oRngCount refers to cells that the abbreviation is to be counted
' Say "HV" is stored in $C16, and the cells to count for HV is D$6:D$15,
' then the sum of HV for that date (D16) is calculated by formula
' `=CountType($C16, D$6:D$15)`

Function CountType(ByRef oRngType As Range, ByRef oRngCount) As Long
    Dim oRngVal As Variant, oVal As Variant, oTmp As Variant, sLookFor As String, count As Long
    sLookFor = Left(oRngType.Value, 2)
    oRngVal = oRngCount.Value ' Load all the values onto memory
    count = 0
    For Each oVal In oRngVal
        If Not IsEmpty(oVal) Then
            For Each oTmp In Split(oVal, ",")
                If InStr(1, oTmp, sLookFor, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then count = count + 1
            Next
        End If
    Next
    CountType = count
End Function
```

Formulas in the sheet:
*Columns to sum are fixed to rows 6 to 15 and Type to lookup is fixed to Column C*
`D16 | =CountType($C16,D$6:D$15)`
`D17 | =CountType($C17,D$6:D$15)`
...
`E16 | =CountType($C16,E$6:E$15)`
`E17 | =CountType($C17,E$6:E$15)`

The way I created the UDF is to lookup and count appearances of a cell value (first argument) within a range of cells (second argument). So you can use it to count a type of treatment for a big range of cells (column G).

Now if you add many columns after F, you just need to use the AutoFill and the appropriate rows and columns will be there.
[image: AutoFill]

You can also create another VBA Sub to add rows and columns and formulas for you, but that's a different question.

Comment: Thanks Patrick - I'm looking into it and there are af ew things that don't fully make sense to me just yet. Now the data I want to be looking at starts at Row 25 Column F and goes all the way down to Row 72 (in terms of counting) and the range expands all the way to AP. This line here I don't really understand. "sLookFor = Left(oRngType.Value, 2)" What value are you assigning here? And the CountType formula won't work because for the Date 17th April( for example) I would then have the formula count all instances of symbol X for that date, and then add it up.

Comment: `sLookFor = Left(oRngType.Value, 2)` gives you the first 2 characters in value of oRngType. Since you are counting the abbreviations, I altered the column C for the Sum to have it in front. The function is used to count number of occurrences of **sLookFor** from the Range (2nd argument).

Comment: Ohhh great! Now I understand what you mean! Thanks very much! It makes sense to me now - I'll give it a shot and let you know how it works out!

Comment: That's great! Thank you so much! I just tried it out and it works like a charm - I just need to extend the CountType($searchableTerm,$RANGE) across, but this automation should save me some time in the future. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's isn't a great idea to have 300 `sum` formulas.

[Name your data range](https://support.office.com/en-NZ/Article/Define-and-use-names-in-formulas-4d0f13ac-53b7-422e-afd2-abd7ff379c64#bmquickly_name_a_cell_or_range_of_cells) and include that inside the `SUM` formula. So each time the NAMED data range expands, the sum gets calculated based on that. Here's how to [create a dynamic named rnage.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/830287)

Sorry I just saw your comment. Following is a simple/crude VBA snippet.

> Range("B3:F12") is rangeValue; Range("C18") is rngTotal.

```
Option Explicit

Sub SumAll()
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim rngSum As Range
Dim rngData As Range
Dim rowCount As Integer
Dim colCount As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim varSum As Variant

    'assuming that your said mechanism increases the data range by 1 row

    Set WS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
    Set rngData = WS.Range("valueRange")
    Set rngSum = WS.Range("rngTotal")

    colCount = rngData.Columns.Count
    'to take the newly added row (by your internal mechanism) into consideration
    rowCount = rngData.Rows.Count + 1

    ReDim varSum(0 To colCount)

    For i = 0 To UBound(varSum, 1)
        varSum(i) = Application.Sum(rngData.Resize(rowCount, 1).Offset(, i))
    Next i

    'transpose variant array with totals to sheet range
    rngSum.Resize(colCount, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(varSum)

    'release objects in the memory
    Set rngSum = Nothing
    Set rngData = Nothing
    Set WS = Nothing
    Set varSum = Nothing
End Sub
```

Screen:

[image]

Comment: I'd love to get this more efficiently done but I don't think it's possible with the lay-out we have. The reason why we have 300 SUM Formulas is that each date needs a different sum count unfortunately..! I tried attaching a picture but for some reason it didn't go through...

Comment: @azurekirby Apologies, I wasn't around. Can you let me know if each day is represented by a column or a row? Because the above snippet I just wrote to cater each column.

Comment: Hi Bon, please refer to the image below I've uploaded. The data is scrubbed already. http://i.stack.imgur.com/mfsXs.png   The data is recorded and summed on a weekly basis. So for the week of 17th of April, the clinician would enter in: HV, HV, SV (therapies completed). This would then be recorded on my second-sheet, the running sheet, which would use my LEN/SUBSTITUTION formula to identify how many instances of HV/SV there are, and then increments its counter. This is then referenced back to the first page.

Comment: @azurekirby is the date that you need total count always today? *e.g. You need count for 15th June, and it's also today's date.* Can you reply to my question, how do you define the week? 5 days week starting from Monday or anyother way?

Comment: Hi Bon, you don't need to worry about counting the date - we would only be looking at the information stored in the 17th April etc. So in weekly increments. Say I have an allocate Date of Oct-14 (They have joined our clinical list then), and then we actually provide them a clinical service say in 17-April, then the clinician will enter in HV under the 17th April Date. So I define a week by setting a fixed date in Cell F23 (17/4/2014) then + 7 to it each iteration up to the 25th of Dec.

Answer (score -1):

You can use named ranges as suggested by bonCodigo or you could use find and replace or you can insert the columns within the data range and Excel will update the formula for you automatically.

Comment: Hi Dan, that won't work either unfortunately. My requirements dictate that I have to show the Total number of medical services delivered for that week (Group Total) as well as the individual break-down per service category item delivered. Each Date Column is made up of 8 sub-items (HV,SV,CV etc.) which then have a LEN(SUBSTITUTE) Formula indicating 1 or 0 if HV/SV/CV etc. was entered. This is then totalled at the bottom. A named range wouldn't solve this problem either I believe :/

Comment: It's sort of hard to help you on this as the sample data you posted is just zero's and I don't think it gives us much to go on, Can you post one of the formulas perhaps? At least with that we can try and break down what you are doing. I know it's obvious to you as you use this sheet but we don't know your data or scenario, The first post made it seem it was just a simple sum(Column 6 to Column 53). Post the formula and we should be able to help further.